# Not able to download game applications from App Store

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-appstore

Since I got my iPad and iPhone I am unable to download certain applications,
especially the games

Is this due to region restrictions with Apple and South Africa?

Apple recently released the iPad to South Africa and in the Apple Store I see the iPad have Angry birds, etc. loaded on them.

But if I try to download it from the App Store I can't.

Comment: Apps not available in your region won't show up in the store at all. What game(s) are you trying to download, and what error message(s) are you getting?

Comment: Like you said. They just don't show up at all when I do a search. When I follow a link from an external source I get a error message, Request cannot be completed.

Answer (score 2):

Per my comment above, apps simply do not show up (in iTunes itself, anyone can view the web-page overview versions) in iTunes if they are not available in your region.

If you do follow a link to the app specifically, you should get an error message explicitly stating that the application is not available.
Any other message indicates some other problem entirely.

[image: App Not Available]

Comment: Is there a place where I can see the restrictions for applications from Apple? Gathering from what you say it sounds like there could be a restriction from South Africa to Apple.

Comment: Check this out: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2642458